# What is the best way to get all the envelopes for a template?

Tags: docusignapi

I have the template id and I want to fetch all the envelopes for this template. What is the right and the best way to get this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if your integration/app sent these envelopes and you put some code that will allow you to do in the future - you can do that.

However, if you have envelopes sent from a template without anything in there to indicate where they came from - there's no way to do that.

The system considers the envelope and template independent objects and there's no correlation (no FKs in the database). When you ask for an envelope to be created from a template, the template is simply copied into a fresh new envelope with everything in it. That's it.

So, for example, if you have unique documents, recipients, fields, etc. etc. you can use them to ascertain the template, but there's nothing directly tying the templateId.

Blog post that covers this topic -
https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/the-trenches-track-your-templates-envelope-custom-fields

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solved it.